# Trouble getting peewee to play nicely with Pycharm - getting unresolved reference

Tags: python, sqlite, pycharm, peewee

I'm new to peewee and trying to do some basic learnings with Python using Pycharm as my IDE. I've installed peewee successfully via 'pip install peewee'. I've also made sure in the interpreter settings that peewee is selected as an available package. However, in my code, I keep getting an "unresolved reference" error on the import peewee line.

I've tried restarting PyCharm a number of times and recreating the default interpreter settings. I've also re-installed Peewee.

Here is the few lines of code I have:

```
from peewee import *

db = SqliteDatabase('journal.db')

class Entry(Model):
    content = TextField()
    timestamp = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)

class Meta:
    database = db
```

when hovering over both "peewee" and "SqliteDatabase" they both show unresolved reference errors. I'm sure I'm missing something simple here...any suggestions??

EDIT:

And here is the full error, not warning, when trying to run the code:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ben.hendricks/PycharmProjects/Console_Journal_App/journal.py", line 1, in 
    from peewee import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'peewee'

Comment: is it error or only warning. Can you run code? Did you try to run it without IDE? This message may have nothing to do with Python and it can be only problem with IDE.

Comment: do you have installed SQLite ?

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying questions. Yes, I've got SQlite installed on my mac as verified by the following command I ran from Terminal: "sqlite3" 

sm7benhendricks:~ ben.hendricks$ sqlite3
SQLite version 3.24.0 2018-06-04 14:10:15
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite>

Comment: And here is the full error, not warning, when trying to run the code:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ben.hendricks/PycharmProjects/Console_Journal_App/journal.py", line 1, in <module>
    from peewee import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'peewee'

Comment: put all error messages in question. They will be more readable and other people may read it. People not always read comments.

Comment: error can means it is not installed. Maybe you have two Pythons installed and you installed peewee with one Python but you run it with different Python. It is common mistake. PyCharm has function (probably in `File->Settings`) to display all avaliable Pythons and modules installed for every Python. There is also function to install new modules in chosen Python.

Comment: Wow, that was it!! Thanks so much. I was going crazy trying figure out why it didn't like it.. Much appreciated!